# Why does instance_eval handle direct accessors in a special way?

Tags: ruby, instance-eval

Why does the following code not raise an error:

```
Object.new.instance_eval { some_accessor_that_does_not_exist= "a value" }
```

While the following would raise a NameError as you would expect:

```
Object.new.instance_eval { some_method_that_doesnt_exist }
```

Even this would raise an error:

```
Object.new.instance_eval { self.some_accessor_that_does_not_exist= "a value" }
```

I've tried this on 1.8.7-p352 as well as 1.9.3-p194 with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Object.new.instance_eval { some_accessor_that_does_not_exist= "a value" }
```

This is interpreted as a creation of new local var named `some_accessor_that_does_not_exist`, not a setter invocation. When you use assignments with implicit receiver, ruby can't know if you wanted to create a local var or call a method, because there's no special syntax for declaring local vars. And so it creates a local var.

But when you use explicit receiver (`self.some_accessor_that_does_not_exist`), then ruby interprets it as a method and fails.

Comment: This was a 'doh' moment for me. 

When I wrote this question I was thinking about things in a method_missing context (trying to resolve a dynamic programming bug) and just didn't process that this is just valid local var setting syntax...

Thanks for the clear answer!

Comment: @Redbeard: It's a pleasure :)